# C program not printing what I'd expect

Tags: c

So I decided to learn C and using learn c the hard way. At any rate I tried editing one of the examples and the output isn't what I expected it would be. I call the program from the command line as e14 asd which "should" print:
    'e' == 101 
    'a' == 97
    's' == 115 
    'd' == 100

But, it doesn't print the 'd' line at all. The code I have is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void print_letters(int argc, char *arg[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < argc; j++) {
        for(i = 0; arg[i] != '\0'; i++) {

            char ch = arg[j][i];
            printf("j is %d and i is %d\n", j, i);

            if(isalpha(ch) || isblank(ch)) {
                printf("'%c' == %d \n", ch, ch);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    print_letters(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming the problem has to do with the argv part but after looking around, I still have no idea what exactly is causing the 'd' not appear.

If someone could explain it to me it's be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you launching the program? Which command line are you using, and which command line parameters are you passing?

Comment: did you try to debug your code ?

Comment: @Jason White i executed your code its printing value i,j and d==100 but as per your problem statement you mentioned that "I still have no idea what exactly is causing the 'd' not appear." but as per executed output "d==100" is displayed ,can you please mentioned more details...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; arg[i] != '\0'; i++) {
```

should be

```
for(i = 0; arg[j][i] != '\0'; i++) {
//            ^^^
```

The loop exit condition should be iterating through the characters of a single command line argument but is actually iterating over the arguments.

Comment: Thanks! It's always the simple things  *sigh*

Comment: @JasonWhite i highly recommend you to start learning how to use a debugger, this kind of errors would be easy to spot using one.

Answer (score 0):

Before you use command-line arguments, you should know that `argc` counts the number of arguments and `argv` is a 2-d array to store the arguments. In this case, for example, if the exe file name is `main.exe` and you type `main.exe asd` in command line, the value of arguments should be: `argc == 2`, `argv[0] == 'main.exe'` and `argv[1] == 'asd'`. For more details about the command-line arguments usage, refer to [Parsing C Command-Line Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/a1y7w461%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)